# How to access data from multiple tabs in Multiplatform iOS Xamarin project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I created a new project by doing File -> New Solution -> Multiplatform -> App -> Native -> Native App in Visual Studio. I am focusing on the iOS side of things.

I am trying to modify this project. In the second tab of the generated app, I need to access all of the Items. Reusing ItemsViewModel seemed like a logical choice. However, the problem is that when I update the data in the second tab, changes are not reflected in the first tab, which is using a separate instance of ItemsViewModel in its respective ViewController.

My questions are:

1. Is there an easy way to have changes in one tab appear in the other?
2. Is it possible for the two tabs to share the same instance of the ItemsViewModel?
3. Is there a completely different solution?

Comment: There are many different ways you could tackle this - it's hard to say which is best without knowing a lot more about your specific requirements.  But sharing a VM instance between two different pages is certainly a viable option.

Comment: Do you know how I could share that instance between two ViewControllers in different tabs? One way could be a singleton class but then it would have global scope which isn't ideal.

Comment: have the TabController create the VM and then pass it to each VM

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, please put solution as answer and accept it so question no longer shows up in search for answered questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a single instance of the ViewModel in the TabBarController. In ViewDidLoad for each of the two ViewControllers where I needed the instance, I accessed the TabBarController's instance.